# What does the direct sum symbol (i.e. $\oplus$) mean in the context of uncertainties

Tags: notation, error-analysis

I've noticed the symbol $⊕$ used in a context I'm unfamiliar with. In several papers about the the calculation of the uncertainty of quantities measured with hadron colliders.

For example the uncertainty in transverse momentum given by:

$$ \frac{ \sigma_{P_{T}} }{ P_{T} } = 0.038\% P_{T}\,({\rm in\,GeV}) ⊕ 1.5\% $$

What exactly does $⊕$ mean in this context?

Comment: It's possibly supposed to be +/-; that is, a typographical error.  Or a font substitution error if this is from online.

Comment: Which several papers? Which pages?

Comment: It is used once here http://arxiv.org/abs/1406.0076 
and i have seen it used more often in presentations like http://www.becher.itp.unibe.ch/LHC/CalorimeterAndJets.pdf
So i don't think it's a typo

Comment: So your only serious reference is a 100-page paper where it's used once, and you can't even provide the page number, even when asked directly?

Comment: Presumably the example you quote is from [this paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1140/epjc/s10052-014-2814-6)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be **addition in quadrature** of multiple independent uncertainties in a measurement. In particular, if you have a measurement which depends on two quantities $a$ and $b$ whose uncertainties $\delta a$ and $\delta b$ are completely independent and uncorrelated, then their uncertainties will often be combined as

$$\delta(a+b)=\sqrt{\delta a^2+\delta b^2}=:\delta a\oplus\delta b,$$

where the symbol $\oplus$ is sometimes used to indicate this method of uncertainty combination.

For more on this procedure see e.g. [this tutorial](http://web.mit.edu/fluids-modules/www/exper_techniques/2.Propagation_of_Uncertaint.pdf#p=5) or simply [google for 'addition in quadrature'](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=addition+in+quadrature); for an explicit example of the $\oplus$ notation used in this sense, see [this CMS page](https://twiki.cern.ch/twiki/bin/view/CMSPublic/TTbarCrossSectionAt13TeV).